# What is the cause of website waiting times?

Tags: wordpress, dns, wait, cdn

I have WordPress website with Woocommerce Shop, and I have around 600 products on it. Using Flatsome theme. When I have noticed that site was slow since It was on Shared Hosting I have moved a website to a new VPS hosting (4GB of RAM and 4GHZ processor) only to realize that wait time is still the same. Also I am using Cloudflare CDN, with no Cache plugin.

https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/cQ1tkm/https://pozivnicezavjencanje.ba/

Can anyone tell me what is causing this long waits?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this first:**

Turn off all plugins, especially WordFence and test again.

**Also, your page has +35 separate script files.**

---

**Now, a bit of background:**

*You are not serving cached pages.*

When a user visits your a page on your website, your server has to "construct" it and that's why it takes time.

*presumably only for first-view because you're using CloudFlare.*

**Cloudflare only caches your content if it has the right headers - and even then, if your data is not cached in the specific CloudFlare CDN Data Center location, it will have to be fetched from your server directly**

Think of it this way,

*Caching is like a xerox machine*. IF you have a xerox machine, you can **just make a copy of the document and serve it almost instantly**.

**Serving dynamic content without caching** is literally like **typing the whole document all over again** - even if you already have the content memorized - **every time it's requested** - it takes more time.

CloudFlare Cache works this way:

it only stores a cached copy of your content if it's only been accessed from that CND Data Center before.

This means the same content from same Data Center location, anything else gets loaded directly from your server - and then it's cached after that.

**Summery:**

*You need a caching solution even if you use CloudFlare*

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that. Any recommended caching plugin? I saw that most people recommend and use W3TC, but I would like to hear it from your angle. Best regards.